# Raspberry PI zero w + Relay HL-56S v1.0

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I have been working in some homemade raspberry project, using node.js to control a relay for some lamps.

I am using:

- raspbery PI  Zero W
- 6 channel relay HL-56S v1.0 (https://www.ptrobotics.com/modulos-de-reles/7671-6-channel-12v-relay-module.html)

Connections:

- Vcc => 5V (pin 2);
- GND => Gnd (pin 6);
- 1In => GPIO 20 (pin 38);

I'm not familiar with the international system so it's hard for me to explain with a correct scheme.

Can you help me with photos?

[image]

[image]

The only problem you have is that with the connections of the images the lamp is always on regardless of the relay status.
You can see that in one photo the relay is off and in the other one it is already on and still the lamp is always on.

Are you finding any problems?

Here's my relevant code:

```js
app.post('/relay(38/on', function(req, res){
  gpio.write(38, false, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Written True to pin 38');
      console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
      return res.render('index', {status: 'Relay 38 is On'});
  });

//RELAY OFF
app.post('/relay/38/off', function(req, res){
  gpio.write(38, true, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Written False to pin 38');
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
      return res.render('index',{status: 'Relay 38 is Off'});
  });
});
});
```

I hope that's enough.

Comment: Sounds like you've connected the lamp in the wrong way. Your picture isn't very helpful.

Comment: Please draw a proper schematic. I think you're very well-intending here, but you'd really have to give us half an hour of introduction into your way of drawing schematics until we understand what you mean, and honestly, I think it still wouldn't tell us what we need to know. So, use the built-in schematic editor of this site, and the internationally standardized symbols for relays and lamps, to make clear what you mean. We don't have the pinouts of these devices in our head, so instead of telling us "there's a pin 1, I connected it to pin 39", label these connections.

Comment: also, don't just "randomly" use tags. Only your [tag:relay] and [tag:raspberry-pi] are relevant, the rest is just "fluff" that makes your question worse to categorize. I'm removing that.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Marcus Müller, but I'm completely new to electronics.It's not easy for me to design a scheme using the editor of this site.
I'm not used to the international standard.
Anyway, as soon as I can I'll try to create a scheme that represents my problem.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @user3752867 it'd be really cool if you could do that, thanks. Also, a datasheet link for your relay would be interesting, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the lamp connected through the "Normally Closed" contact of the relay (which I can barely see if the photo is brightened and contrast reduced to extremes). So the fact it's not turning off indicates that the relay is not actually pulling in.

[image]

You have purchased a 12V relay module, so it needs 12V to operate. The LED only indicates that the input signal to the optoisolator has been received, not that the relay is functioning.

Comment: Tks for your anwser! : ) So do I need to buy a 5V relay or is there a way to use this?

Comment: You can provide a 12V supply to the module (see the module instructions) or you can buy a 5V module (and give it 5V). Normally you'd want to connect the lamp through the normally open contacts, but I don't know the details of your application (power off means the light would be 'off' then, rather than 'on' as you have it).